# JMeter embedded resources not named correctly

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I'm using an HTTP sampler to download embedded resources. Here's is the example from python.org. I was expecting the the names of the embedded resources to match the actual request. But instead they're named the same as the parent sample. Could be by product of HTTPS? I'm using JMeter 5.3.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a part of enhancement introduced in [JMeter 5.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-new-jmeter-5), see [Bug 62550 - Modify SubResult Naming Policy](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62550) for details.

If the previous behaviour is really what you're looking for you can get it back in 2 ways:

1. Tick "Functional Test Mode" box at [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) level

   [image]
2. Add `subresults.disable_renaming=true` line to [*user.properties* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#sample_results)

Answer (score 0):

when you record the transaction it should generate the sample names normally.

Are you using parallel controller ?
Actually you can tweak with settings of naming policy in jmeter properties.
[image: Naming Policy]